# How to solve the anchor certificate expired?

Tags: ios, https

First of all, thank you for attention to this problem.

Access the server with anchor certificate, certificate expires in the application cannot be normal visit, now has the following solutions:

1. Set the certificate time: `SecTrustSetVerifyDate (trust: SecTrust,verifyDate:CFDate)`
2. The application of the certificate expires force users to update

Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Are you asking about certificate pinning, and strategies for updating the certificate in the client app? The question as written is not very clear.

Comment: Yes, certificate (server.cer, will expire on January 1, 2017) put in the Bundle, the server after the renewal, if the user doesn't update App cannot access the server normally.

Comment: there are many ways to do this, and it depends on your situation. This question is not on topic for Stack Overflow. Consider moving to security.stackexchange.com where this question (with improvements to mention certificate pinning) will get better responses.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion.